# How to stop execution of python script in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following code which I am running from within Visual Studio Code using `Right click > Run Python File in Terminal`

```
import threading


def worker(tid):
    """This is what the thread actually executes"""
    for i in range(tid * 100000):
        print("I'm working on thread {} with count {}".format(tid, i))
    return


def main():
    threads = list()
    for i in range(32):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However I want to stop the execution of the script so I have tried with `Ctrl+C` but the program is still running in the integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code. Is there a way to actually force the stop?

Comment: There is a difference between `code running` and `task running`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There should be a trashcan at the top of the integrated terminal window. Clicking the trashcan will kill the window and the processes.

You can also try ctrl-Z or ctrl-D.

Comment: is there any visual indication that a script is running in VSCode?

Comment: Only clicking trashcan helped

Comment: the trashcan works however it closes the terminal. It would be nice to be able to stop a script with the terminal still open, so you can see a 'script ended/interrupted' message in the terminal.

Comment: neither of these work in version 1.75.0 --- only the trash can

Comment: ctrl+c seems to work just like in Powershell or GitBash. Upvoting because it got me to try it.

Answer (score 11):

Try: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, that should do it.

Comment: for me didn't work

Answer (score 8):

You could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then `Terminal: Relaunch Active Terminal`

Or create a shortcut for it

Answer (score 5):

You may want to install [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) in the visual studio extensions. :) I feel that killing the terminal by clicking on the trash bin is a bit tiring for me because I need to open the terminal again.

Answer (score 5):

Right clicking on the integrated terminal window, then clicking 'Kill Terminal' worked for me.