# VS code notebook output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

sometimes if my output is too long I am not able to open it in text editor. Normally I used to change code to print in loop, but its too tedious to do this every time. Is there some option to change it?

didnt found any option in vs code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR6hF.png)

Comment: It may solve your problem: 
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385276/how-to-stop-execution-of-python-script-in-visual-studio-code
2. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#:~:text=To%20work%20with%20Python%20in,Ctrl%2BShift%2BP).

Answer (score 0):

You can search `notebook.output.textLineLimit` in settings.

You can modify the number here:

[image]